# Error 500 and SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when fetching data from Prisma in NextJs13

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, prisma

I have these functions; one for getting data and one for updating data. The `useEffect` should get the wish-list from the database when the `currentUser` exists:

```
const handleAddToWishlist = async (product) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      toast("Trebuie să fiți autentificat pentru a adăuga produse în coș.", {
        duration: 5000,
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/wishlist`, {
        method: "POST",
        signal: signal,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          user_id: currentUser.id,
          productId: product.id,
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const isProductInWishlist = wishlist.some(
          (item) => item.id === product.id
        );

        if (isProductInWishlist) {
          dispatch(removeFromWishlist(product));
          setAdded(false);
          toast.success("Produsul a fost eliminat din favorite");
        } else {
          dispatch(addToWishlist(product));
          setAdded(true);
          toast.success("Produsul a fost adăugat la favorite");
        }
      } else {
        toast.error("Eroare. Încearcă din nou!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding to wishlist:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.id) {
      const fetchWishlist = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/wishlist?id=${currentUser.id}`);
        const data = await response.json();

        if (!data) {
          return;
        } else {
          dispatch(setWishlist(data));
        }
      };
      fetchWishlist();
    }
  }, [currentUser]);
```

I use route handlers and these are in folder api/wishlist/route.js. With the get request I get error 500 and with the post request I get SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. I will want for the Get request a way to handle if the wishlist doesn't exist in the database.

```
import db from "@/prisma/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const id = searchParams.get("id");

  const wishlist = await db.favorite.findFirst({
    where: {
      user_id: id,
    },
  });
  return NextResponse.json(wishlist);
}

export async function POST(req) {
  const data = await req.json();
  const { user_id, productId } = data;

  const wishlist = await db.favorite.upsert({
    where: { user_id: user_id },
    create: {
      user_id: user_id,
      produse: JSON.stringify([productId]),
    },
    update: {
      produse: {
        push: productId,
      },
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(wishlist);
}

{
  /* export async function POST(req) {

  const list = await db.favorite.findUnique({ where: { user_id: id } });

  let favorites = list.favorite ? JSON.parse(user.favorite) : [];

  favorites.push(productId);

  // Update the user's favorites in the database
  const wishlist = await db.favorite.update({
    where: { id: id },
    data: {
      favorite: JSON.stringify(favorites),
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(wishlist);
} */
}
```

This is the prisma schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model comenzi {
  id               Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  data             DateTime?   @db.Date
  produse          String?     @db.Text
  pret             Decimal?    @db.Decimal(10, 2)
  adresa_livrare   String?     @db.VarChar(200)
  adresa_facturare String?     @db.VarChar(200)
  status           String?     @db.VarChar(50)
  client_id        Int
  utilizatori      utilizatori @relation(fields: [client_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "comenzi_ibfk_1")

  @@index([client_id], map: "client_id")
}

model favorite {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  produse_id  Int?
  user_id     Int?
  produse     produse?     @relation(fields: [produse_id], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "favorite_ibfk_1")
  utilizatori utilizatori? @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "favorite_ibfk_2")

  @@index([produse_id], map: "produse_id")
  @@index([user_id], map: "user_id")
}

model produse {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  nume      String     @db.VarChar(50)
  link      String     @db.VarChar(45)
  pret      Int
  cantitate String     @db.VarChar(50)
  stoc      Int
  tip       String     @db.VarChar(50)
  descriere String?    @db.Text
  imagine   String?    @db.Text
  favorite  favorite[]
}

model utilizatori {
  id       Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  nume     String     @db.VarChar(50)
  telefon  String     @db.VarChar(20)
  email    String     @db.VarChar(100)
  password String     @db.VarChar(255)
  comenzi  comenzi[]
  favorite favorite[]
}
```